# Express make try/catch block into middleware to avoid duplication

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, try-catch

Im writing my expressJs application, and Im finding in my routes controller the same duplicated code for catching exception, I was wondering how to avoid this.

I have checked this thread, but I get this error `"Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined"` : [Express Try and Catch in Form of middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68463549/express-try-and-catch-in-form-of-middleware)

this is my route.js

```
const express = require("express");
const createHttpError = require("http-errors");
const Validator = require("../middlewares/Validator");
const TaskNotFoundException = require("../services/TaskNotFoundException");
const TaskService = require("../services/TaskService");

router.get("/tasks", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = await TaskService.getTasks();
    res.send({ code: 200, message: "Success", data });
  } catch (error) {
    next(createHttpError(500));
  }
});

router.get("/task/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    const data = await TaskService.getTask(id);
    res.send({ code: 200, message: "Success", data });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof TaskNotFoundException) {
      next(createHttpError(404));
    } else {
      next(createHttpError(500));
    }
  }
});
and the list goes on
```

as you see in all my routes I have a try catch block with the possible errors (either only a 500, or a 500/404). And I would like to avoid this repetition.

this is my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const createHttpError = require("http-errors");
const api = require("./routes/api");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/api", api);

// Catch HTTP 404
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createHttpError(404));
});

// Error Handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      status: err.status || 500,
      message: err.message,
    },
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Like I said, it works perfectly now, I would just like to try to avoid the try catch code duplication, and Ive checked the other questions in Stackoverflow but havent helped. The solution ive linked returns a 500 with this catch undefined message (which is not what I want) and on other routes that also have a 404 it just doesnt work.

Thanks a lot!

---

Update:
I followed Heikos advice but still not working

api.js

```
const express = require("express");
const createHttpError = require("http-errors");
const Validator = require("../middlewares/Validator");
const TaskNotFoundException = require("../services/TaskNotFoundException");
const TaskService = require("../services/TaskService");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/tasks", async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = await TaskService.getTasks();
  res.send({ code: 200, message: "Success", data });
});
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const createHttpError = require("http-errors");
const api = require("./routes/api");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/api", api);

function catchAsyncErrors(middleware) {
  return async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      await middleware(req, res, next);
    } catch(err) {
      next(err);
    }
  };
}

// Catch HTTP 404
app.use(catchAsyncErrors((req, res, next) => {
  next(createHttpError(404));
}));



// Error Handler
app.use(catchAsyncErrors((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      status: err.status || 500,
      message: err.message,
    },
  });
}));

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code inside your async middleware functions contains an `await`, you must also wrap it in a `try-catch` block, otherwise a rejected promise will be unhandled. For example:

```js
app.use(async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    await Promise.reject("error");
  } catch(err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

propagates the error to the error handler, but without the `try-catch` block it leads to an "UnhandledPromiseRejection".

You can save some typing if you wrap your middleware into a `catchAsyncErrors` function:

```js
function catchAsyncErrors(middleware) {
  return async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      await middleware(req, res, next);
    } catch(err) {
      next(err);
    }
  };
}
router.get("/tasks", catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = await TaskService.getTasks();
  res.send({ code: 200, message: "Success", data });
}));
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more? I still do not have a middleware to substitute these try/catch block in my routes

Comment: I think you need a try-catch block in every middleware.

Comment: I did this, added teh catchAsyncErrors function you proposed and wrapped my Catch 404 error and Error Handler middlewares on it, but still not working (getting the same UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning log error)

Comment: Can you update your question with your latest code, reduced to just what's needed to reproduce the error?

Comment: I made an update with my recent code. thanks man

Comment: You did not wrap the middleware in the `router.js` file. The unhandled rejection probably comes from there.

Comment: Sorry I dont follow, by router.js you mean api.js? which middleware? My middlewares are defined in app.js and I wrapped them in the catchAsyncErrors function. If youre telling me to wrap the controller route, thats what I did in the beginning when I asked the question and it works (check the first code extract). But precisely I would like a way to avoid having to wrap every route in a try/catch blog to avoid duplicating this in all the routes I have

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant `api.js`, see my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response hehe. This fixed it, im gonna mark this answer as the correct one. thanks a lot man!